# Javascript: error 403 occurs in HTTP GET requests, some minutes after loading page

Tags: javascript, get, fetch, http-status-code-403, httpserver

I have developed a JavaScript code that sends periodically, every 500 msec, a GET request to an HTTP server, which answers to this request with text data in JSN format.

```
function get(theUrl, success, failure, commData)
{
    commData = commData || {};
    return fetch(theUrl)
    .then(function(res)
    {
        if (!res.ok)
        throw Error(res.statusText);
        return res;
    })
    .then(function(res)
    {
        return res.text();
    })
    .then(function(html)
    {
        success(html, commData);
    })
    .catch(function(error)
    {
        failure(commData);
    });
}
```

This javascript code is part of the resources (js, css, images) that are downloaded along with the index.html from the HTTP server.

The client receives answer from the server without any problem for some minutes. Suddenly, around 15 minutes after the download of the index.html, the browser inspector shows that the client starts receiving systematically error 403 ("forbidden") to the GET request. This happens with any browser (at least with Firefox, Chrome and IE/Edge). When the 403 error occurs, the failure() function of the above code sample is triggered.

I have monitored the connection with Wireshark, and I could see that, in spite of the 403 error, actually the HTTP server is still receiving the request and is sending the (correct) answer.

It looks like that in the browser there is some timer that is started when loading the home page (index.html), and which expires after some minutes, causing the fetch() API to fail with error 403.

I need that the periodical GET can works indefinitely, without limit of time, because its purpose is to monitor the state and retrieve important diagnostic data from an embedded system.
How can I solve it?

EDIT:
First of all; I have to correct the text and the title of this post, because the "forbidden" error is not 503, but 403. I apologize for the mistake.

Secondly, I am adding some useful information. The webserver is running on RTOS in a Concerto F28M36x processor. In order to make a simulation test and to debug more easily, I adapted the code of webserver in order to have it running on a Window machine, using the MSDN C++ HTTP API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/http/http-server-api-overview). In this scenario, the HTTP server is running on the same computer of the client (localhost). Nevertheless, the behavior (with error 403) is exactly the same, as when the webserver is running in the embedded system. Here is what is shown by the browser inspector, when the GET request is successful (result=200):

```
GET http://localhost/readResults.cgi
Status 200 OK
Version HTTP/1.1
Transferred 308 B (174 B size)
Referrer Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response header: (157 B)
Content-Length 174
Content-Type text/plain
Date Tue, 06 Apr 2021 11:00:39 GMT
Server Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
    
Request headers (421 B):
Accept */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
cache-control no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0
Connection keep-alive
expires Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT
Host localhost
pragma no-cache
Referer http://localhost/
Sec-GPC 1
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0
```

And this is shown by the browser inspector when the result is 403:

```
GET http://localhost/readResults.cgi
Status 403 Forbidden
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transferred 4.11 KB (3.95 KB size)
Referrer Policy no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response header: (157 B)
Cache-Control no-cache
Connection close
Content-Length 4047
Content-Type text/html; charset=UTF-8
Proxy-Connection close

Request headers (421 B):
Accept */*
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
cache-control no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0
Connection keep-alive
expires Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT
Host    localhost
pragma  no-cache
Referer http://localhost/
Sec-GPC 1
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0
```

As one can see, with respect to the "good" case, in the "bad" case the following additional fields are present in the response header:

```
Connection: close
Proxy-Connection: close
```

---

Edit - since I am not receiving any answer, could somebody please suggest me a different forum where I can post this question?

---

Edit - just a gentle reminder. Any suggestion?

Comment: _“It looks like that in the browser there is some timer that is started when loading the home page (index.html), and which expires after some minutes, causing the fetch() API to fail with error 503.”_ - sounds like pure conjecture to me. Have you first of all checked, what the server error log has to say?

Comment: The server doesn't have any error. As I wrote, the server receives the GET and answer it correctly, as Wireshark shows. Everything looks normal on the server side

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the puzzle.
The connection is blocked by the Sophos firewall, which has some restrictions against running http server.

In fact the issue happens only in the desktops and laptops of my corporation (in which the Sophos firewall is installed). In other computers the http server works fine for hours or days.